# Elastic Search:Update of existing Record (which has custom routing param set) results in duplicate record, if custom routing is not set during update

Tags: elasticsearch, routes, partitioning, sharding

Env Details:
Elastic Search version 7.8.1
routing param is an optional in Index settings.

As per ElasticSearch docs - https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/mapping-routing-field.html

*When indexing documents specifying a custom _routing, the uniqueness of the _id is not guaranteed across all of the shards in the index. In fact, documents with the same _id might end up on different shards if indexed with different _routing values.*

We have landed up in same scenario where earlier we were using custom routing param(let's say customerId). And for some reason we need to remove custom routing now.
Which means now docId will be used as default routing param. This is creating duplicate record with same id across different shard during Index operation. Earlier it used to (before removing custom routing) it resulted in update of record (expected)

I am thinking of following approaches to come out of this, please advise if you have better approach to suggest, key here is to AVOID DOWNTIME.

**Approach 1:**
As we receive the update request, let duplicate record get created. Once record without custom routing gets created, issue a delete request for a record with custom routing.

CONS: If there is no update on records, then all those records will linger around with custom routing, we want to avoid this as this might results in unforeseen scenario in future.

**Approach 2**
We use Re-Index API to migrate data to new index (turning off custom routing during migration). Application will use new index after successful migration.

CONS: Some of our Indexes are huge, they take 12 hrs+ for re-index operation, and since elastic search re-index API will not migrate the newer records created between this 12hr window, as it uses snapshot mechanism. This needs a downtime approach.

Please suggest alternative if you have faced this before.

Comment: Approach 2 sounds more sustainable. Somehow, you need to redirect the creation of all the new documents to a new index (without routing) and migrate old data from the old index to the new one (approach 2 with reindex). During the migration, your application will need to somehow query both indexes.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks @Val, also found few other approaches like write to both indexes and read from old. And then shift to read new one after re-indexing is finished. Something on following lines -

1. Create an aliases pointing to the old indices (*_v1)
2. Point the application to these aliases instead of actual indices
3. Create a new indices (*_v2) with the same mapping
4. Move data from old indices to new using re-indexing and make sure we don't
   retain custom routing during this.
5. Post re-indexing, change the aliases to point to new index instead of old
   (need to verify this though, but there are easy alternatives if this
   doesn't work)
6. Once verification is done, delete the old Indices

**What do we do in transition period (window between reindexing start to reindexing finish) -**

Write to both Indices (old and new) and read from old indices via aliases